# Display views in custom eclipse perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, view, eclipse-plugin, perspective

I have a perspective which i have made, and a bunch of views i would like to be able to display on this perspective. If i go Window -> Show View -> Other and then select my view it works fine. However i would like to show a view by default upon opening the perspective and place it where the project explorer usually would be.

But nothing i do seems to change anything and i cannot find any reason why.
I have been using this code to try to change the location of this view but it doesn't even open the view by default. can someone point me in the right direction on how to open a view by default and place it where the project explorer usually would be?

```
public class PerspectiveFactory1 implements IPerspectiveFactory {
    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        layout.addView("VIEW_ID_HERE", IPageLayout.LEFT,
            IPageLayout.RATIO_MAX, IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Here is my plugin.xml

```
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            class="packageName.PerspectiveFactory1"
            fixed="true"
            id="PerspectiveID"
            name="Software Application">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
      <perspectiveExtension
            targetID="PerspectiveID">
         <view
               class="packageName.ShowApplications"
               icon="icons/sample.gif"
               id="packageName.ShowApplications"
                   minimized="false"
                   moveable="false"
                   name="listApps"
                   ratio="0.5"
                   relationship="left"
                   visible="true">
             </view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have the project explorer in that perspective you can't use its id in the reference id parameter to addView. Instead use the editor area id which is always allowed:

```
layout.addView("view id", IPageLayout.LEFT,
    0.3f, layout.getEditorArea());
```

You may also have to Reset the perspective if it has been open before to get the new layout picked up (Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective).

The view must be defined using the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point.

You can also use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` to define the position of a view in the perspective instead of the perspective factory - but this still requires the view to be defined using `org.eclipse.ui.views`.

Comment: your code works great if i use an eclipse default view like IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER as the id. However when i put in my string ID it does not display anything. Currently the ID on my view is the same as the class e.g. packageName.views.className. Do i need to reference this in a different way?

Comment: No, it is always just the view id. [edit] your question and show us the `org.eclipse.ui.views` definition of your view in your plugin.xml

Comment: That should be what you are after.

Comment: That is a perspective extension, it does **not** define a view, it just says where to put an existing view in the perspective. `class` and `icon` are not actually valid there. You must use `org.eclipse.ui.views` to actually define the view.

Comment: so i dont need the perspectiveExtension?

Comment: You can use either the perspectiveExtension **or** the perspective factory, but not both for a single view. If you have several views in a perspective you can mix the two but again just one or the other for each view. The intention is that the 'core' views for a perspective are defined in the perspective factory, and other plugins can add to that using perspective extensions.

Comment: Brilliant it now almost works!. It loads the area and moves it to the left however view is blank any ideas? here is what it is complaining about Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView' from bundle '1109'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver       I have got the driver inside of the project and have added the driver to the build path via add jar.

Comment: You must add jars you want to use to the Bundle-Classpath in the MANIFEST.MF (and they must be part of the plugin). In the MANIFEST.MF/plugin.xml/build.properties editor add to the 'Classpath' section on the 'Runtime' tab. Also add the jar to 'build.properties'